# XLS/CSV data export using Thingsboard 2.2-PE

Tags: csv, format, decimal, separator, thingsboard

Is it possible to change decimal separator (AKA format number) in exported data from the "Export to CSV/XLS" function, enabled in the top-right part of a widget?

Thank you

Edit:
Below you can find all the actions, using Thingsboard GUI, and also the exported result.

[Fig. 1 - Thingsboard Widget with some values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deMG8.png)

[Fig. 2 - Exporting action by User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAha7.png)

[Fig. 3 - Decimal separator dot was used for thousand and also for decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqJYB.png)

Comment: Kindly post some of your code and also refer to this [ask]

Comment: I @PrabhjotSinghKainth and thank you for your comment. I did it. I hope it's clear now. KR